# task completion

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, threadpool

I have a loop that creates multiple tasks as shown below. 
How do I update the screen (add a new line to a textbox with some data) as each task completes?

How do I detect when all tasks are complete?

**C# Code**

```
 for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(radTextBoxFloodRequests.Text); i++)
 {
      int x = i;
      // Create a task and supply a user delegate by using a lambda expression. 
      var taskA = new Task(() => TaskRequest(int.Parse(radTextBoxFirstNumber.Text), int.Parse(radTextBoxSecondNumber.Text), int.Parse(radTextBoxFloodDelay.Text), x));
      // Start the task.
      taskA.Start();
 }


 private void TaskRequest(int number1, int number2, int delay, int count)
 {
      // Some long running method
 }
```

Comment: you want to get a trigger when all your tasks are done?

Comment: yes, and as each task completes also

Comment: Are Parallel.For or Parallel.ForEach a solution for you? Hard to really understand what you are looking for.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`ContinueWith()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx):

> *"Creates a continuation that executes asynchronously when the target Task completes."* - MSDN

```
Task t = new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("")).ContinueWith(task => Console.Writeline("Continue With"), 
                                                            TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: You need to add the paramater TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext if you're going to update the UI, you might be on a different thread.

Comment: Before the last bracket add  ", TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext"

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use a combination of 3 simple constructs:

- a simple `int numActiveTasks`, that is incremented with `InterlockedIncrement(ref numActiveTasks)` on task creation, i.e. immediately before `taskA.Start()` and decremented with `InterlockedDecrement(ref numActiveTasks)` at the end of the task, i.e. at the end of the function `TaskRequest(...)`
- a `ManualResetEvent`, that is reset before task start and signalled on task end **after** the counter decrement
- a thread, that `WaitOne()`s on the `ManualResetEvent`, then reads `numActiveTasks`

This gives you

- notfication of single task done
- notification of all tasks done (numActiveTasks<=0)

The main advantage of this is, that you have souvereignity about on which thread the notification occurs.

Comment: hi, can you please provide some code for this to illustrate how this is done?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `Parallel.ForEach()` ?

```
    [Test]
    public void ParallelTasks()
    {
        var strings = new List<string> {"task1", "task2", "task3"};

        Parallel.ForEach(strings, str => Console.WriteLine(str + "is done"));

        // All your parallel tasks are executed now
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on User 12345678's answer, you could do something like the below.

```
    private void RunTasks()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> kvp in dict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Executing task " + kvp.Key + " ...");
            Task t = new Task(() => MyMethod(kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
            tasks.Add(t);
            t.Start();
            t.ContinueWith(task => Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + " completed"));

        }

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting tasks to complete...");
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine("All tasks completed...");
    }

    private void MyMethod(string arg1, string arg2)
    {

    }
```